# gulp converting React module to class error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6

after converting a simple react module to es6 class; i got some gulp parsing errors.

```
    var React = require('react');
    // import React from 'react';
    class UdpComp extends React.Component {

      constructor (props){
         super(props);
         this.state = { udpinput: props.udpinput };
      },
      render: function() {
        return(
            <div className="udpText">
                <h2>UDP-INPUT: {this.state.udpinput}</h2>
           </div>
        ) // return
      } // render
    })// UdpComp

    export default UdpComp;
```

ok, my gulpfile.babel.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
    concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    run = require('gulp-run');

var src = './process',
    app = './app';

var sassOptions = {
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
}; // https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-gulpy-workflow-sass/


gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src( src + '/js/apprender.js' )
     .pipe(browserify({
      transform: 'reactify',
      extensions: 'browserify-css',
      debug: true
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(app + '/js'));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src( src + '/**/*.html');
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src( src + '/css/*.css')
  .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(concatCss('app.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(app + '/css'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    gulp.src('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(app + '/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function() {
  gulp.watch( src + '/js/**/*', ['js']);
  gulp.watch( src + '/css/**/*.css', ['css']);
  gulp.watch([ app + '/**/*.html'], ['html']);
});

gulp.task('serve', ['html', 'js', 'css'], function() {
  run('electron app/main.js').exec();
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'fonts', 'serve']);
```

when calling gulp I get

> \process\js\UdpCompReact.js: Parse Error: Line 14: Unexpected
>   identifier error

why, how can I parse es6 code?

Comment: you also have a typo. the closing curly bracket of your class has a parenthesis which is not needed anymore

Answer (score 1):

Can't see what's on line 14 but I'd guess it's the comma right after your constructor. As opposed to ES5 "classes", ES6 classes don't require (and don't allow) commas between methods. Just remove it and it should work (or at least get past line 14)

Answer (score 0):

You need a transpiler that converts it to ES5, afterwards pipe it in the gulp task. I use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and there is a [gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) npm package

Comment: ok, I fixed the ;, issue...  now I got an error Parse Error: Line 3: Illegal import declaration when i am using import React from 'react';

Comment: I think there's a problem transpiling import React from 'react';

Comment: Can you update the post with te newest version of your code? There shouldnt be a problem with that line

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this, when using the older version the transpiling works.
import React from 'react' throws an error.

```
// var React = require('react');
import React from 'react';

class UdpComp extends React.Component {

  constructor (props){
     super(props);
     this.state = { udpinput: this.props.udpinput };
  }


  render () {
    return(
        <div className="udpText">
            <h2>UDP-INPUT: {this.state.udpinput}</h2>
       </div>
    ) // return
  } // render



}; // UdpComp

module.exports = UdpComp;
// export default UdpComp;
```